# How do I know if an object is a Objective-c object and therefore is handled by ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I saw a response in S.O. that indicated if an object is NOT a Objective-c object, it is not subject to ARC memory management, and therefore has to be released by me in my code.

So with that in mind, how do I determine if an object (i.e. CFGregorianDate) is an Objective-c object and therefore falls under ARC or not?  Is there a list somewhere? (I looked and couldn't find one).

Comment: An Objective-C object can be represented by an `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold down the `option` key and click on the name.  If it is a `class`, it defines an Objective-C object.  If it is a `structure` it is a C structure.

You may or may not have to free a C structure depending on whether it is on the
stack or in the heap:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // This is a stack-base structure.  It doesn't have to be freed.
    CFGregorianDate mydate;

    mydate.year = 2013;
    mydate.month = 10;
    mydate.day = 20;
    mydate.hour = 11;
    mydate.minute = 30;
    mydate.second = 45;

    // This is a heap-based structure.  If must be freed.
    CFGregorianDate *mydate2 = (CFGregorianDate *)malloc(sizeof(CFGregorianDate));
    mydate2->year = 2013;
    mydate2->month = 10;
    ...

    free(mydate2);
```

Answer to followup question:

A lot of Apple's low level interfaces are still in C.  OpenGL stuff, address book, core graphics.  The best advice I have is to look at Apple's documentation when calling a function you've never used before, especially if it is creating something big for you like an image.  Beware if the interface is a C interface (which you can easily recognize because parameters are passed one right after the other separated only by commas).  Objective-C interfaces feature brackets (`[` and `]`) and the parameters are all proceeded by keywords with a colon at the end.  Apple's documentation will tell you if you are responsible for freeing a structure.

Comment: So, just to make sure I understand, CFGregorianDate is a C structure, therefore I have to release it myself, yes?

Comment: C structures can be created on the stack, in which case you don't have to free them.  If you called a memory allocation function like `alloc` or `malloc` to allocate it on the heap, then you'll need to call `free` to free the memory.  If you just declared one in your function and filled it in, then it is a stack variable and its memory will be freed when you leave the function.

Comment: `release` is specifically for Objective-C objects.  You'd never call `release` on a C structure.

Comment: I'm confused... there has to be more than it's either a C-type structure or it's a class... can you give me some examples of each?

Comment: @spokane-dude... Just look out for things allocated with `alloc`, `malloc`, `calloc` and such.  Those are the ones that need to be `free`d.  You're not likely to see these much unless you yourself are using them or you are using someone else's library code that uses them.  Apple's C-based interfaces usually just use small C structures that can easily be created on the stack.

Comment: OK... for instance, in this code:

[imageView setImage:[UIImage    
        imageWithCGImage:CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([originalImage CGImage], rect)]]; 

ARC doesn't handle retain/release of Core Foundation objects for me.  This is what I'm having a problem with... there was NO alloc for the above object.  

Let me ask the question another way:  What else besides Core Foundation objects fall into this category where I have to do the release?

Comment: You also need to look for memory syntax conventions when using Foundation/C libraries. 'create' and 'new' both return non-objective C objects that must be released (so in this case, CGImageCreateWithImageInRect you're not balancing, because it contains the word create and you're not subsequently calling CGImageRefRelease on that CGImageRef).

Answer (score 1):

Can you call methods on it? If so, it's an object. Is the interface to it all C functions? Not an object.

(edit) Except for dispatch_* and xpc_*, sigh. The trickery they do does break the general rule

Comment: Also tricky: You can call methods on the result of CFArrayCreate and the like due to toll-free bridging.

Comment: Not under ARC though, you'd need to bridge cast or CFBridging*()

Answer (score 1):

An Objective-C class is specified by an @interface block. If a type is specified that way, it's an Objective-C class. Look at the CFGregorianDate header — does it include an Objective-C class definition? No.

In general, a framework will either use Objective-C-style objects or CoreFoundation-style objects. CoreFoundation (home of CFGregorianDate) obviously uses the latter. Cocoa uses the former.